# Frustum Culling, implementation

Tags: math, opengl, 3d, d, linear-algebra

I am currently trying to implement frustum culling (again) for my world. My world consists of chunks with the size 16x256x16 (x, y, z):

```
Frustum frustum = Frustum(engine.proj * engine.view);

foreach(chunkc, chunk; chunks) {
    vec3i w_chunkc = vec3i(chunkc.x*16, chunkc.y*256, chunkc.z*16);

    AABB aabb = AABB(vec3(w_chunkc), vec3(w_chunkc.x+16, w_chunkc.y+256, w_chunkc.z+16));
    if(aabb in frustum) {
        bind(engine, chunk);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, cast(uint)chunk.vbo_vcount);
    }
}
```

`chunkc` holds the coordinates of the whole `chunk` e.g. `[0, 0, -2]`. So to get the chunks bounding box, I have to multiply these coordinates by the size of each chunk to get the minimal position of the AABB and add the size to each component to get the max. position of the AABB. Then I check this AABB against the frustum.

Frustum implementation:

```
struct Frustum {
    enum {
        LEFT, /// Used to access the planes array.
        RIGHT, /// ditto
        BOTTOM, /// ditto
        TOP, /// ditto
        NEAR, /// ditto
        FAR /// ditto
    }

    Plane[6] planes; /// Holds all 6 planes of the frustum.

    @safe pure nothrow:

    @property ref Plane left() { return planes[LEFT]; }
    @property ref Plane right() { return planes[RIGHT]; }
    @property ref Plane bottom() { return planes[BOTTOM]; }
    @property ref Plane top() { return planes[TOP]; }
    @property ref Plane near() { return planes[NEAR]; }
    @property ref Plane far() { return planes[FAR]; }

    /// Constructs the frustum from a model-view-projection matrix.
    /// Params:
    /// mvp = a model-view-projection matrix
    this(mat4 mvp) {
        planes = [
            // left
            Plane(mvp[0][3] + mvp[0][0], // note: matrices are row-major
                mvp[1][3] + mvp[1][0],
                mvp[2][3] + mvp[2][0],
                mvp[3][3] + mvp[3][0]),

            // right
            Plane(mvp[0][3] - mvp[0][0],
                mvp[1][3] - mvp[1][0],
                mvp[2][3] - mvp[2][0],
                mvp[3][3] - mvp[3][0]),

            // bottom
            Plane(mvp[0][3] + mvp[0][1],
                mvp[1][3] + mvp[1][1],
                mvp[2][3] + mvp[2][1],
                mvp[3][3] + mvp[3][1]),
            // top
            Plane(mvp[0][3] - mvp[0][1],
                mvp[1][3] - mvp[1][1],
                mvp[2][3] - mvp[2][1],
                mvp[3][3] - mvp[3][1]),
            // near
            Plane(mvp[0][3] + mvp[0][2],
                mvp[1][3] + mvp[1][2],
                mvp[2][3] + mvp[2][2],
                mvp[3][3] + mvp[3][2]),
            // far
            Plane(mvp[0][3] - mvp[0][2],
                mvp[1][3] - mvp[1][2],
                mvp[2][3] - mvp[2][2],
                mvp[3][3] - mvp[3][2])
        ];

        normalize();
    }

    /// Constructs the frustum from 6 planes.
    /// Params:
    /// planes = the 6 frustum planes in the order: left, right, bottom, top, near, far.
    this(Plane[6] planes) {
        this.planes = planes;
        normalize();
    }

    private void normalize() {
        foreach(ref e; planes) {
            e.normalize();
        }
    }

    /// Checks if the $(I aabb) intersects with the frustum.
    /// Returns OUTSIDE (= 0), INSIDE (= 1) or INTERSECT (= 2).
    int intersects(AABB aabb) {
        vec3 hextent = aabb.half_extent;
        vec3 center = aabb.center;

        int result = INSIDE;
        foreach(plane; planes) {
            float d = dot(center, plane.normal);
            float r = dot(hextent, abs(plane.normal));

            if(d + r < -plane.d) {
                // outside
                return OUTSIDE;
            }
            if(d - r < -plane.d) {
            result = INTERSECT;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// Returns true if the $(I aabb) intersects with the frustum or is inside it.
    bool opBinaryRight(string s : "in")(AABB aabb) {
        return intersects(aabb) > 0;
    }
}
```

And the AABB implementation:

```
struct AABBT(type) {
        alias type at; /// Holds the internal type of the AABB.
        alias Vector!(at, 3) vec3; /// Convenience alias to the corresponding vector type.

        vec3 min = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); /// The minimum of the AABB (e.g. vec3(0, 0, 0)).
        vec3 max = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); /// The maximum of the AABB (e.g. vec3(1, 1, 1)).

        @safe pure nothrow:

        /// Constructs the AABB.
        /// Params:
        /// min = minimum of the AABB
        /// max = maximum of the AABB
        this(vec3 min, vec3 max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        /// Constructs the AABB around N points (all points will be part of the AABB).
        static AABBT from_points(vec3[] points) {
            AABBT res;

            foreach(v; points) {
                res.expand(v);
            }

            return res;
        }

        /// Expands the AABB by another AABB.
        void expand(AABBT b) {
            if (min.x > b.min.x) min.x = b.min.x;
            if (min.y > b.min.y) min.y = b.min.y;
            if (min.z > b.min.z) min.z = b.min.z;
            if (max.x < b.max.x) max.x = b.max.x;
            if (max.y < b.max.y) max.y = b.max.y;
            if (max.z < b.max.z) max.z = b.max.z;
        }

        /// Expands the AABB, so that $(I v) is part of the AABB.
        void expand(vec3 v) {
            if (v.x > max.x) max.x = v.x;
            if (v.y > max.y) max.y = v.y;
            if (v.z > max.z) max.z = v.z;
            if (v.x < min.x) min.x = v.x;
            if (v.y < min.y) min.y = v.y;
            if (v.z < min.z) min.z = v.z;
        }


        /// Returns true if the AABBs intersect.
        /// This also returns true if one AABB lies inside another.
        bool intersects(AABBT box) const {
            return (min.x < box.max.x && max.x > box.min.x) &&
                (min.y < box.max.y && max.y > box.min.y) &&
                (min.z < box.max.z && max.z > box.min.z);
        }

        /// Returns the extent of the AABB (also sometimes called size).
        @property vec3 extent() const {
            return max - min;
        }

        /// Returns the half extent.
        @property vec3 half_extent() const {
            return 0.5 * (max - min);
        }

        /// Returns the area of the AABB.
        @property at area() const {
            vec3 e = extent;
            return 2.0 * (e.x * e.y + e.x * e.z + e.y * e.z);
        }

        /// Returns the center of the AABB.
        @property vec3 center() const {
            return 0.5 * (max + min);
        }

        /// Returns all vertices of the AABB, basically one vec3 per corner.
        @property vec3[] vertices() const {
            return [
                vec3(min.x, min.y, min.z),
                vec3(min.x, min.y, max.z),
                vec3(min.x, max.y, min.z),
                vec3(min.x, max.y, max.z),
                vec3(max.x, min.y, min.z),
                vec3(max.x, min.y, max.z),
                vec3(max.x, max.y, min.z),
                vec3(max.x, max.y, max.z),
            ];
        }

        bool opEquals(AABBT other) const {
            return other.min == min && other.max == max;
        }
    }

    alias AABBT!(float) AABB;
```

So far in theory, unfortunatly I get completly wrong results, in certain dirctions (`z-` and `x+`) the whole world disappears and in all other directions nothing is culled.

I hope anyone of you has an idea why this doesn't work.

**EDIT (different method of checking AABB agains Frustum):**

```
bool intersects2(AABB aabb) {
    foreach(plane; planes) {
        if(plane.a * aabb.min.x + plane.b * aabb.min.y + plane.c * aabb.min.z + plane.d > 0 )
            continue;
        if(plane.a * aabb.max.x + plane.b * aabb.min.y + plane.c * aabb.min.z + plane.d > 0 )
            continue;
        if(plane.a * aabb.min.x + plane.b * aabb.max.y + plane.c * aabb.min.z + plane.d > 0 )
            continue;
        if(plane.a * aabb.max.x + plane.b * aabb.max.y + plane.c * aabb.min.z + plane.d > 0 )
            continue;
        if(plane.a * aabb.min.x + plane.b * aabb.min.y + plane.c * aabb.max.z + plane.d > 0 )
            continue;
        if(plane.a * aabb.max.x + plane.b * aabb.min.y + plane.c * aabb.max.z + plane.d > 0 )
            continue;
        if(plane.a * aabb.min.x + plane.b * aabb.max.y + plane.c * aabb.max.z + plane.d > 0 )
            continue;
        if(plane.a * aabb.max.x + plane.b * aabb.max.y + plane.c * aabb.max.z + plane.d > 0 )
            continue;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Edit 2 (Example input):**

Here is a MVP:

`[[1.18424,0,0.31849,-331.577],
    [0.111198,1.51016,-0.413468,-88.5585],
    [0.251117,-0.274135,-0.933724,214.897],
    [0.249864,-0.272768,-0.929067,215.82]]`

And a possible failing AABB:
`min: (14*16, 0, 13*16)
   max: (14*16+16, 256, 13*16+16)`

Comment: Which line exactly isn't giving you the result you expected?

Comment: It's the first code, it doesn't cull as it should, if you need a line: `if(aabb in frustum)` gives wrong results.

Comment: Right. And which line within that function isn't giving the result you expect? You just need to dive in and figure out where the problem is function by function. There's no magic to debugging.

Comment: That's what I am doing for the last 2 days. The problem is, everything seems correct to me. So my hope is, someone sees the problem, e.g. maybe I am using the coordinates in the wrong space (one thing I could think of) everything else seems to be fine, e.g. I also implemented 3 different methods of finding out if the AABB is inside or outside (all had the same results). My knowledge ends here, that is why I am asking on SO, because here are people with more/other knowledge.

Comment: Everything cannot be correct. One of the planes in `intersects` must be returning OUTSIDE. Which one? What are the dot products? Are they what you expect? If not, why not.

Comment: It "seems correct to me". Well basically everything is wrong there. Since it returns OUTSIDE for chunks which are inside, and the other way round (I also tried different implementations: see following edit), which returned the same false results. So I think the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: If the function is not giving the correct result then either the algorithm is wrong, or the inputs are wrong. Find out which are work from there.

Comment: That's where I am struggling, I'll test a different method of creating the frustums planes tomorrow, but according to multiple so called "tutorials" and codes I've looked at, this also seems to be correct.

Comment: You **do not** debug by trying a different algorithm! Find out why this one isn't working first. All the code is there. You have all the numbers. Just keep narrowing down the problem until you know exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: Can you provide an input where the function returns the wrong value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have the answer now ... a really stuipid thing, I didn't think of.

I did what "Peter Alexander" suggested and tried to debug everything ... I ended up finding out that the frustum-planes are completly wrong (left and right planes normals were pointing at the same direction) so I messed with my code and other example codes and found out, the the matrix wasn't transposed (I store it as row-major, opengl as column.major), so a simple: `mvp.transpose()` in the Frustum-Ctor fixes my frustum.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your dot product approach does work (made a small [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VS7Uf/) to test it), but it seems to me that your frustum is being setup incorrectly with:

```
Frustum(engine.proj * engine.view)
```

instead of:

```
Frustum(engine.model * engine.view * engine.proj)
```

notice both the **order** ([matrices are anti-commutative!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#All_matrices)) and the **additional multiplication of the model matrix** so that you create the MVP matrix.

Comment: So I should setup my frustum like this: `auto frustum = Frustum(engine.view * engine.proj)` (my model-matrix never changes, it's always an identity matrix). I tried it, now nearly every AABB was flagged as "outside".

Comment: Since he's using OpenGL, the transformations must be performed backwards, hence the the projection matrix * view matrix. This is because GL uses column-major storage.

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem with the way you're initializing your `AABB` class.  I don't know if this is what is causing your problem, but it's worth fixing anyway (to guard against accidentally using the broken initialzer sometime).

For a default `AABB` (which seems to be what you're starting out with when making one `from_points()`), both corners are set at `(0,0,0)` -- so, when constructed this way, every AABB must contain the origin.

If you must set up a default `AABB` like this, you need to make the default `min=(infinity,infinity,infinity)` and `max=(-infinity,-infinity,-infinity)`.

Comment: Thanks, this should be changed, but unfortunatly that isn't the solution to the problem, since I never use `.from_points` and I printed the AABBs to check if they are correct and they are correct e.g.: `[304,0,336] [320,256,352]` where the first is `min` and the second `max`.